# Handle Like in react-native

Tags: react-native

I have a variable called `upvote` and they contain the number of Upvotes (ex: 1,2..).

In my API I have a check like this -

```
 const product = require("./images/like_blue.png");
  const product1 = require("./images/like.png");

    if(res.success == true && res.like == true){
                    console.log(res.upVote);
                    changeBlue();
                    this.setState({upVote:res.upVote});
                  } else if(res.dislike == true && res.success == true) {
                    this.setState({upVote:res.upVote});
                    changeGrey(); 

    }
```

Now in my constructor  and render function

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          likeImage:product1,
          upVote: this.props.data.upVote
        };
      }
changeBlue() {
    console.log("color change called blue");
    this.setState(prevState => ({ likeImage: product }));
  }

  changeGrey() {
    console.log("color change called");
    this.setState(prevState => ({ likeImage: product1 }));
  }
    render()
    {
    return(
    <view
    <Image source={this.state.likeImage}/>
    </view>
    );
    }
```

See if my like equals true, then the upvote value increase otherwise it decreased. 
So in my render function, i have a view and on this, i have set `likeimage` by default I  want to change my `likeimage` if like == true otherwise remains default. This is working fine.

My image get change if get "Liked" or "disliked".But there is one problem if i go out of the app and open it again, my change image looks the same old image

note : The state will always load the image you defined initially, since it is relative to component level, and on refresh it will go away, unless saved somewhere, perhaps in the [AsyncStorage]: I don't know how i do this .please help me out here

Comment: Save the state in SharedPreference and set the image based on that.

Comment: I' have no idea about, infact i used async storage for set and get item but how i set image in render?

Comment: save the like state  in async storage, get that value in the component will mount and save that shared preference value in a different state variable ,based on that state show whichever image you want to use in render, You can use ternary operator. {condition?view1:view2} in render like this.